# Telebit autostart

Tags: raspberry-pi, autostart

I am currently working on a project with alexa skill to control a raspberry pi remotely.

https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/develop-your-own-raspberry-pi-alexa-skill-and-control-pi-remotely/

As endpoint for alexa skill i want to use telebit.
Normaly I start telebit from the terminal and everything works fine.

`sudo ./telebit http 5000`

Now I want to start it automatically when starting the raspberry pi. For that i use the raspberry pi GUI.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=telebit
Exec=lxterminal -e bash -c 'sudo /home/pi/telebit http 5000;$SHELL'
Terminal=true
```

And I get this error message.

```
(unix socket: /root/.local/share/telebit/var/run/telebit.sock)

/home/pi/Applications/telebit/bin/telebit-remote.js:643
  var verstrd = [ pkg.name + ' daemon v' + state.config.version ];
                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
    at handleConfig (/home/pi/Applications/telebit/bin/telebit-remote.js:643:57)
    at /home/pi/Applications/telebit/bin/telebit-remote.js:359:22
    at /home/pi/Applications/telebit/usr/share/install-launcher.js:236:24
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:296:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
```

I also tried rc.local and .bashrc but I always get the same error message.

Maybe some of you can help me

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. You just have to omit sudo.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=telebit
Exec=lxterminal -e bash -c '/home/pi/telebit http 5000;$SHELL'
Terminal=true
```